# Ошибка при подключении к удаленной папке между двумя Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, path

Всем привет! Я пытаюсь получить доступ к данным из расшаренной папки на Ubuntu, используя Python скрипт. Когда я подключаюсь с Windows:

```
import os
from shutil import copy
print(os.listdir("//myhost/rr"))
```

Все работает. Но когда я пытаюсь точно так же подключиться с другого Ubuntu, то он выдает ошибку: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//myhost/'`.

Comment: `os.listdir` принимает только пути в вашей локальной файловой системе и не умеет работать с произвольными URL

Comment: А где лежит та папка? ``//myhost`` не похоже на валидный путь в линуксе.

Comment: @andreymal Тогда почему мне выводились файлы из этой директории, когда я запускала скрипт на Windows?

Comment: @arti_lina потому что Windows умеет обрабатывать такой формат путей. А в линуксе такого никогда не было и вряд ли появится в будущем (как и в macOS и вообще всех остальных ОС), и Python тут в общем-то ни при чём

Comment: @Эникейщик Эта папка лежит на "сервере" Ubuntu. Я пытаюсь получить к ней доступ из "клиента", который тоже на Ubuntu и скрипт, который отрабатывает в Windows, не работает для моего "клиента" Ubuntu.

Comment: @andreymal А какие есть альтернативы, не подскажете? В эту директорию приходят файлы, которые нужно мгновенно считывать и выводить, т.е. использовать mount и перебрасывать их на мой "клиент" Ubuntu будет занимать какое-то время. Или без mount тут не обойтись?

Comment: @arti_lina видимо только mount. Ну или может попробовать переписать скрипт под какой-нибудь [pysmb](https://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), но это не точно

Comment: @andreymal спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: `smb://myhost/rr`

Comment: Gvfs-fuse и подключайтесь

Comment: @PavelGridin os.listdir так не умеет